# Libvirtd TCP port 16514 queries

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt

I have a server that is running libvirtd. I just checked libvirtd ports and see below output. I wondered Why port 16514 PID is always 1 and why tcp6 is handling ipv4 with multi connections.

Can anyone please let me know.

```
root@prd-140:~# netstat -anpt |grep 16514
tcp6       0      0 :::16514                :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd
tcp6       0      0 10.1.6.140:16514       10.2.127.52:60556     ESTABLISHED 12289/libvirtd
tcp6       0      0 10.1.6.140:16514       10.2.127.52:29463     ESTABLISHED 12289/libvirtd
```

```
root@prd-140:~# lsof -i :16514
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
systemd      1 root   59u  IPv6  9761899      0t0  TCP *:16514 (LISTEN)
libvirtd 12289 root    5u  IPv6  9761899      0t0  TCP *:16514 (LISTEN)
libvirtd 12289 root   30u  IPv6 20539283      0t0  TCP prd-140:16514->10.2.127.52:60556 (ESTABLISHED)
libvirtd 12289 root   35u  IPv6 20549679      0t0  TCP prd-140:16514->10.2.127.52:29463 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Comment: `lsof -i :16514` on the host, share the output by editing the question please

Comment: Hi, Updated with lsof info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The first part is about systemd's socket-based activation.
- The second part is about IPv4/IPv6 dual stack handling

### systemd's socket-based activation

> [systemd.socket](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html):
>
> A unit configuration file whose name ends in ".socket" encodes
> information about an IPC or network socket or a file system FIFO
> controlled and supervised by systemd, for **socket-based activation**.

> For each socket unit, a matching service unit must exist [...]

> Note that the daemon software configured for socket activation with
> socket units needs to be able to accept sockets from systemd, either
> via systemd's native socket passing interface (see [sd_listen_fds(3)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_listen_fds.html#)
> for details about the precise protocol used and the order in which the
> file descriptors are passed) or via traditional [inetd(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?inetd(8))-style socket
> passing (i.e. sockets passed in via standard input and output, using
> StandardInput=socket in the service file).

This feature is an improvement over what the *inetd* ("internet super-server") could provide, but can require additional support from the application (for systemd's native socket passing interface).

libvirtd does offer such support:

> [Monolithic Systemd Integration](https://libvirt.org/daemons.html#monolithic-systemd-integration)
>
> When the libvirtd daemon is managed by systemd a number of desirable
> features are available, most notably socket activation.

> - `libvirtd.service` - the main unit file for launching the libvirtd daemon in system mode.

> - `libvirtd.socket` - the unit file corresponding to the main read-write UNIX socket `/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock`.

Here it apppears OP's settings aren't just using the default unix socket but enabled [TLS remote connections](https://libvirt.org/remote.html#transports).

The goal is to let *systemd* manage the socket without having to run *libvirtd* until a request on this socket is received. *systemd* will then start the *libvirtd* service which inherits the socket.

### IPv6 uses IPv4/IPv6 dual stack mode

The 2nd feature is just how dual IPv4/IPv6 stack works: use the IPv6 API, get IPv4 for free. This can be disabled with the `IPV6_ONLY` socket option, but the default is to be dual stack, as encouraged in RFC 3493: Basic Socket Interface Extensions for IPv6:

> [5.3 IPV6_V6ONLY option for AF_INET6 Sockets](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3493#section-5.3)
>
> This socket option restricts AF_INET6 sockets to IPv6 communications
> only. As stated in section <[3.7 Compatibility with IPv4 Nodes](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3493#section-3.7)>, AF_INET6 sockets may be used for both IPv4 and IPv6 communications.

> By default this option is turned off.

meaning that by default IPv6 can handle IPv4 on a system following RFCs and with an application not actively disabling this feature.

`netstat` chooses to display a plain IPv4, but for example the local address seen on the established *sockets* is actually an [IPv4-mapped IPv6 address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses): `::ffff:10.1.6.140` (or `::ffff:0a01:068c`) as would `ss -anpt` display instead on Linux. The address on the *wire* stays of course a normal IPv4 address.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. We see the connection is still in ESTABLISHED state and don't see any traffic exchange.
```
root@prd-140:~# timeout 180 tcpdump -nvvv -i loopback host 10.2.127.52 and port 16514

tcpdump: listening on loopback, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes

0 packets captured
0 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Comment: @user5016380 if your question was about an unexpected security breach, then I really couldn't guess it. I just answered to what you asked, and don't intend to address a security problem. Also: if you listen on *loopback* you can't capture remote traffic. And for proper syntax usually on Linux the interface should have been be named *lo* not even loopback. You usually (there are exceptions for this) have to listen on the interface where the address 10.1.6.140 was added instead.